# splitting a string column correctly by spaces

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, tokenize, charindex

in my query I have several hundred records with strings from the iSeries Message Queue like this:

```
006 1 AccountSetBalance 0000000000 EQ 2016-03-01-18.45.42.002000 0038882665 _ 123456 12345612345678 17017362 0 0
```

I need to show in my results the account number part `12345678` and the balance part which is `17017362`

I have tried:

```
SELECT MQ_Message
, SUBSTRING(MQ_Message,92,30) -- = 12345678 17017362 0 
, SUBSTRING(MQ_Message,92,8) -- = 12345678  , SUBSTRING(MQ_Message,100, CHarIndex(' ',  SUBSTRING('006 1 AccountSetBalance 0000000000 EQ 2016-03-01-18.45.42.002000 0038882665 _ 123456 12345612345678 17017362 0 0',92,20)) )
, CHarIndex(' ',  SUBSTRING('006 1 AccountSetBalance 0000000000 EQ 2016-03-01-18.45.42.002000 0038882665 _ 123456 12345612345678 17017362 0 0',99,20)) 
, CHARINDEX(' ','17017362 0 0')
    from outboundMessages WHERE message_Type = '006'
```

I can get the account easily enough, as the string is fixed length up to the balance, but then I need to split the string returned by `SUBSTRING(MQ_Message,92,30)` and get the balance part out of it which is `17017362` and will be different between **0** and maybe **999999** (in pence!)

I am really stuck trying to get the balance, having tried every possible combination of using CHARINDEX.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I split a string so I can access item x?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/how-do-i-split-a-string-so-i-can-access-item-x)

Comment: So, did you try my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @string NVARCHAR(MAX) =  '006 1 AccountSetBalance 0000000000 EQ 2016-03-01-18.45.42.002000 0038882665 _ 123456 12345612345678 17017362 0 0',
        @xml xml

select @xml = cast('<d><q>'+REPLACE(@string,' ','</q><q>')+'</q></d>' as xml)

SELECT n.v.value('q[9]','integer'),
       n.v.value('q[11]','integer')
FROM @xml.nodes('/d') AS n(v);
```

Result:

```
----------- -----------
123456      17017362

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Thanks! Glad to help!